# Difficulty reading cursive lettering

Tags: перевод

I hope to be making more progress soon but forgive me my humble beginnings. I have great difficulty reading cursive lettering sometimes, which is somewhat of a starting point. I have this single line which is actually very important for me to understand, so are you able to aid me unpicking it? I would be most grateful. I have had to upload it to another page because I can't see how to upload images here.

[image]

Comment: I followed your link and got a message "You cannot access this album". But in the question editor here there is a button for adding images, in line with other formatting buttons above the area for question text. Don't you have it?

Comment: That's just some address in Saint-Petersburg.

Comment: @shabunc, this is another of your because-I-can closings. At the very least, you're quoting an irrelevant rule. This question is asking for something altogether different from a translation.

Comment: @NikolayErshov, I encourage you to create a topic at meta if you believe that this is on-topic. I believe it is not - it does not help other Russian language learners.

Comment: @shabunc https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/424/another-question-closed-by-shabunc-on-dubious-grounds

Answer (score 5):

First three letters is `СПБ` - unofficial abbreviation of `Санкт-Перербург`. Next: `Московский пр. д 95` - Moskovskij avenue(`проспект` - I'm not sure in correct translation), building 95.

Comment: Thank you very much.The strange thing is that I suspected the translation but just could not pick out the letters. It is like knowing the answer but not being able to prove it!

Comment: it looks like the building's number is 85, not 95

Comment: @user907860 Yes, it's possible, but I'm sure that it is 95. Some people write top round of sign "9" clockwise, and than add a "tail". But others begin to write top round counterclockwise, and sharp corner at the middle of the number on the picture is consequence of changing direction of a pen. I have never seen such corner in "8".

Comment: "СПБ" is a _very_ official abbreviation, for centuries.

Comment: BTW, *Moskovskiy ave, 95* is a police department of Moskovskiy district (УМВД России по Московскому р-ну Санкт-Петербурга) while *Moskovskiy ave, 85* is an office building.

Comment: And it's something strange, because the address is a living address. Maybe Moskovskiy ave, 85 is partly living or there is any other number, but I don't know certainly.

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit it that cursive handwriting is very often of very bad quality, especially if made by someone who has to do a lot of paperwork as a part of his job. So it's totally OK if you struggle with undestanding it.

Different people often write the same letters completely differently, thus making the letters seem to be the same when they are not. Some occasionally write the same letter in 2 or even more different ways (for no reason).

My advice would be: practice on printed texts in *Italic fonts*. That should help.